# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezing after suspend

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my dell inspiron 7000 series, I know that there are some compatibility issues with some of the newer drivers (I already had to fix a bug with my graphics driver).  Ubuntu runs just fine, but when I suspend it or close the lid of my laptop, I cannot get it to start up again.  I either get a black screen, or a frozen login screen an I have to do a hard shutdown and restart to get it to work again.

After some research I found that it could be something wrong with the kernel, (I was running 4.10, but I tried running it on version 4.6 and got the same result).  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks

System specs

1 tb HDD,
intel i7- 7th gen quad core,
nvidia gtx 1050ti with DDR4,
16gb ram 2400 mHz

Answer (score 2):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and a Dell PC, in my case this problem appeared when I tried to install the proprietary software for my video card.

Since I came back to my previous driver the problem didn't appear anymore.

I hope that it's useful.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, Ubuntu was having problems with 4k resolution, so I just changed the resolution, and it works now.